# HFSS port 'Port1' does not have a valid reference plane above or below it

Tags: rf, balun

How to get rid of the following errors:

> planar_marchand_balun (C:/Users/kevin/Documents/Ansoft/)
>     EMDesign1
>
> [error] An error occurred during the mesh generation. Check the message window for additional details. (11:06:56 am  Jul 06, 2019)
>
> [error] HFSS port 'Port1' does not have a valid reference plane above or below it. (11:06:56 am  Jul 06, 2019)
>
> [error] HFSS port 'Port2' does not have a valid reference plane above or below it. (11:06:56 am  Jul 06, 2019)
>
> [error] HFSS port 'Port3' does not have a valid reference plane above or below it. (11:06:56 am  Jul 06, 2019)

[image: reference plane error]

Answer (score 1):

I'm relatively new to HFSS myself, so keep that in mind.

When I had a similar error with one of my designs, it was because I didn't define a ground plane in the wave port definition under excitation in the project tree in the left column.

From what I understand, the wave port defines an electric field between two conductors at the port location in the model. You need to tell HFSS where the voltage potential is at the port. In other words, which conductor has a positive potential, and which conductor is used as the ground reference.

Its hard to tell from your image, but I don't see any ground plane, or any ground conductors that can be used as a common reference or ground between ports.

You might need to add a ground plane under your model structure (or around the structure) and define the plane as a reference in the wave port properties.

Comment: Ticking "negative" box for bottom layer within the stackup dialog solved the issue

Comment: However, the simulation result does not converge: "Adaptive Passes did not converge based on specified criteria."

Comment: I have managed to make the simulation converged, but the s-parameter [magnitude](https://i.imgur.com/6pSoVRv.png) and [phase](https://i.imgur.com/IvHHftN.png) results make the layout looks like not a [marchand balun](https://i.imgur.com/mVDyhKR.png). Why ? Note that the via is not visible at the end of each strip for ports 2 and 3. I am still trying to make the via visible

Comment: [I have now added the via correctly and the two vias are visible now.](https://i.imgur.com/QNNuLE0.png)

However, the magnitude and plot simulation results remain unchanged. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

If the port definitions are correct and the simulated results don't match what is expected, I would first verify that all materials are defined properly, and that the mesh is fine enough to give an accurate result.
You can define a very fine mesh on regions of interest to give a more accurate result.